# Sort List of string based on value in Dict

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a List of strings named `frequentItems` and a Dict named `mis` (Multiple Item Support value) whose values are floats. The relationship between the two is that any element of `frequentItems`, `i` is a key to `mis` so that `mis[frequentItems[i]]` returns a float value.

I would like to sort `frequentItems` based on the float values returned from `mis[frequentItems[i]]` but am unsure how to specify this using `.sort()` or `sorted()`. I have basically no experience using `lambda` but think it is what I need to specify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't even need the `lambda` here, you can simply use `dict.get` to get the value corresponding to the elements of the list.

```
frequentItems.sort(key = mis.get)
```

**Example:**

```
mis, frequentItems = {1: 3.4, 5: 3.14, 3: 7.5}, [1, 3, 5]
frequentItems.sort(key = mis.get)
print(frequentItems)  # [5, 1, 3]
```

Comment: So simple, bless Python. Thank you

Comment: Be careful with this one on python3.3.  Your example code won't work if the list contains an item which isn't a key in the dictionary since `None` can't compare to `float`.  In that case, you *need* @JoranBeasley 's `lambda` solution where you explicitly provide a comparable type to `get`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def getItem(itemName):
    return mis.get(itemName)

frequentItems.sort(key=getItem)
```

you could of coarse rewrite `getItem` as a lambda function

```
getItem = lambda itemName:mis.get(itemName,None)
frequentItems.sort(key=getItem)
```

you could include it as key directly as a lambda

```
frequentItems.sort(key= lambda itemName:mis.get(itemName,None))
```

you could simplify your argument to a single letter

```
frequentItems.sort(key= lambda i:mis.get(i,None))
```

while the lambdas are shorter they can be slower

(or use thefourtheye's much better solution for this actual problem :P)

Comment: 1. `cmp` is entirely different from `key`, cmp should return `-1, 0 or 1`, I believe. 2. And `dict.get`, by default returns `None`. So, you can simply do like in my answer.

Comment: bah :P thanks .... I got sidetrack on lambdas while you actually answered the question

Comment: @JoranBeasley, Thanks for posting `lambda` examples